# Understanding the phrasing "[Line] $L$ is perpendicular to $N=(5,-7)$". How can a line be perpendicular to a point?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 326)

> Example. Let $L$ be the line defined by the equation $5x- 7y=9$,
> and let $L'$ be the line defined by the equation $3x+4y= 2$.
> Then $L$ is perpendicular to $N = (5, -7)$ and $L'$ is perpendicular to $N' = (3,4)$.

Isn't the concept of perpendicularity only defined for lines (or segments) ? Why does the author uses it when mentioning points ?

I see, in this particular example, that the author points out that a line can be perpendicular to a specific point on the plane.

Comment: I suspect that $(5,-7)$ is meant to be a vector here, not a point.

Comment: Thank you, @Angina Seng. Is perpendicularity defined for vectors ? Perhaps, I am missing what you just explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line can't be perpendicular to a point. The author is likely referring to vectors with endpoints at the origin and the ordered pair.

Comment: Thank you. Is line $L$ perpendicular to vector $N=(5, -7)$? Shouldn't be line $L$ perpendicular to the segment $\overline{ON}$ ?

Comment: @F.Zer Assuming $O$ is referring to the origin, segment $\overline{ON}$ and vector $N$ are one and the same with the exception that vector $N$ has an orientation in space. They coincide with each other, so it doesn't matter. The fact that a vector $N=(5,-7)$ implies that it starts at $(0,0)$ and ends at $(5,-7)$.

Comment: Good. Thinking a bit more, I really should say directed line segment $\overrightarrow{ON}$